# Connection between proof and algebraic factor theorem

Tags: linear-algebra

It is (no proof needed)
Let $f \in End(V)$ and $ f^2 = f$ Then $V = Ker(f) \oplus Im(f)$.

What does this mean for the following sentence??

"Factor Theorem. Let $F : V \to W $ be linear and $A = (u_1, ..., u_r, v_1, ..., v_k)$ be a Basis of V with ker(F) = span$(v_1, ..., v_k).$ 
By definition of $U = span(u_1, ..., u_r)$ we get:

1) $ V = U \oplus Ker(F)$

2) The Restriction $F|U: U \to Im(F)$ is an isomorphism

3) If $P: V = U \oplus Ker(F) \to U, v = u + v' \to u$ is the projection, so $F = (F|U) \circ P$.

Thank you very much for any kind of help, since I'm a bit confused :)

Well what I did see is that I proofed $V = Ker(f) \oplus Im(f)$. So according to 1) it is $Im(f) = U$....

Comment: When you have $V=U\oplus W_1$ and $V=U\oplus W_2$, you can only conclude $W_1 \simeq W_2$, not $W_1=W_2$. Now this theorem says that by forgetting the subspace $\ker(F)$ where $F$ is $0$, one obtains an injective linear map. And by forgetting the vectors of $W$ that aren't touched by $F$, one obtains the isomorphism of 2). 3) says that from the decomposition $U\oplus\ker(F)$ and $F_{\mid U}$ one recovers $F$ by putting $F(x) = 0$ for $x\in\ker(F)$, and extending linearly.

Comment: Hello. Thank you, but I still have some questions. 1) Why do I obtain an injective linear map by forgetting the subspace ker(F)? 2) Forgetting the vectors of W means forgetting the vectors of V sind my f is an endomorphism (f: V -> V) ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll expand here my comment, and try to answer to your second question.

Let us consider the general case where $F : V\rightarrow W$ is a homomorphism, and not an endomorphism of $V$.

- If $V = U\oplus \ker(F)$, then $f_U : U\rightarrow W$ defined by $F_U(x) = F(x)$ is an injective homomorphism. Indeed, its kernel is $\{x\in U : F_U(x) = 0\} = \{x\in U : F(x) = 0\} = \{x\in U : x\in \ker(F)\} = U\cap \ker(F)$ and this intersection is trivial (i.e, it is $\{0\}$) by definition of the direct sum. Hence $F_U$ is injective.
- Considering $F_U$ as a mapping between $U$ and $\mathrm{im}(F)$. This means that we forget about vectors that are in $W$ but that are not reached by $F$. This mapping is still injective, and now it is surjective: if $y\in \mathrm{im}(F)$ then by definition there is $x\in V$ such that $F(x) = y$. Consider the decomposition of $x$ as $x = u + n$, where $u\in U$ and $n\in\ker(F)$ (this exists by definition of direct sum, and is unique). Then $F(u) = F(x) - F(n) = F(x) - 0 = F(x)$ so that $F(u) = y$ and $u\in U$, i.e $y$ has a preimage by $F_U$ and $F_U$ is surjective. Hence $F_U : U\rightarrow \mathrm{im}(F)$ is an isomorphism.

Hence it *always* holds that if $V=U\oplus \ker(F)$, then $U\simeq \mathrm{im}(F)$, and you can derive from this fact the rank theorem: $\dim(V) = \dim(\ker(F)) + \mathrm{rk}(F)$.

In your special case where $F$ is an endomorphism, you have furthermore that $\mathrm{im}(F)\subseteq V$ and $F^2 = F$, and only with these hypotheses it is possible to prove that $V = \mathrm{im}(F) \oplus \ker(F)$.

Hoping this will help you see clearer.

Comment: This really was a very good comment and great explaining. I thank you very much, you made me happy after having a long working-day ;-)